# After payment in paytm stage environment android webview goes to https://developer.paytm.com/txn-response

Tags: android, payment-gateway, paytm

I am stuck in a weird situation, while integrating paytm payment gateway on android app. Using **appinvokesdk**. After webview redirecting to payment gateway, i done staging payment success and it goes to https://developer.paytm.com/txn-response and stuck, instead of going to onActivityResult.

Below is my code.

// app gradle

```
implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.6.0'
```

// project gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.paytm.in/libs-release-local"
        }
    }
}
```

// CheckoutActivity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG ,"onActivityResult - resultCode " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == PaytmRequestCode && data != null) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                Log.i(PG_TAG, key + " : " + (bundle.get(key) != null ? bundle.get(key) : "NULL"));
            }
        }
        /*if(bundle.get("STATUS").toString().equals("TXN_SUCCESS")) {
            processing_app_payment(bundle);
        }*/
        Log.e(PG_TAG, "data - " + data.getStringExtra("nativeSdkForMerchantMessage"));
        Log.e(PG_TAG, "data response - " + data.getStringExtra("response"));
        //General.showToast(mContext, data.getStringExtra("nativeSdkForMerchantMessage") + data.getStringExtra("response"));
    } else {
        General.showToast(mContext, "Payment Failed");
    }
}
```

and i am calling ...

```
public void initializePaytmPayment(String txn_token, String callbackurl, String id, String order_ref, String net_order_total) {
        String paymentUrl = "";
        if(PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT.equals("TEST")) {
            paymentUrl = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/showPaymentPage";
        }
        if(PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT.equals("PROD")) {
            paymentUrl = "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/showPaymentPage";
        }
        PaytmOrder paytmOrder = new PaytmOrder(order_ref, PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID, txn_token, net_order_total, callbackurl);

        TransactionManager transactionManager = new TransactionManager(paytmOrder, new PaytmPaymentTransactionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTransactionResponse(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                General.showToast(mContext, "Payment Transaction response " + bundle.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void networkNotAvailable() {
                General.showToast(mContext, "networkNotAvailable");
            }
            @Override
            public void onErrorProceed(String s) {
                General.showToast(mContext, "onErrorProceed - " + s.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void clientAuthenticationFailed(String s) {
                General.showToast(mContext, "clientAuthenticationFailed - " + s.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void someUIErrorOccurred(String s) {
                General.showToast(mContext, "someUIErrorOccurred - " + s.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onErrorLoadingWebPage(int i, String s, String s1) {
                General.showToast(mContext, "onErrorLoadingWebPage - " + s.toString() + ", " + s1.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onBackPressedCancelTransaction() {
                General.showToast(mContext, "Back Pressed or Cancelled Transaction");
            }
            @Override
            public void onTransactionCancel(String s, Bundle bundle) {
                General.showToast(mContext, "onTransactionCancel - " + s.toString() + ", " + bundle.toString());
            }
        });

        //transactionManager.setAppInvokeEnabled(false);
        transactionManager.setShowPaymentUrl(paymentUrl);
        transactionManager.startTransaction(this, PaytmRequestCode);
    }
```

after doing payment webview going to https://developer.paytm.com/txn-response. please see screenshot.
[image]

I am not getting the reason why this is happening. Please help, thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the response after the transaction (use the test url) based on the docs of the payment gateway, the call or the processing could be attached to a POST method and because of that there must be a Reply in the result that you should manage in your app maybe with the GUI, check https://developer.paytm.com/docs/authenticate-subscription/

Comment: i am getting signature and checksum properly also getting txnToken with response code 0000 (success) as result of initiateTransaction api, process followed from  https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/
The problem is that after i am not getting the response , before this webview goes to https://developer.paytm.com/txn-response (url found from console).

Comment: Alright and if there is a dashboard for the Admin, can you see if the transaction went successful or it doesn't? If it was success you should program to redirect back to home screen maybe, or to a different screen or widget (for user experience purposes I guess)